# Split Date range over the months considering 26th as first day of month and 25th as last day of month

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Rephrase : I have following date ranges for the calculation and expected results,
I want to split revenue over the months for given date range with 26th taking as month start date and 25th as month end date.
See picture

Table 
[image]

Comment: Is there a typo in `Endate : 15/09/2017` ?

Comment: Apologize for typo in endate it's 15/09/2017

Answer (score 0):

I believe there are many mistakes in your sample data and expected result. Guess you are looking for something like this

```
DECLARE @startdate DATE = '2017-07-14',
        @enddate   DATE = '2017-09-15'

SET @startdate = Datefromparts(Year(@startdate), Month(@startdate) - 1, 26);

WITH cte
     AS (SELECT FirstDayOfMonth = @startdate,
                LastDayOfMonth = Dateadd(dd, -1, Dateadd(month, 1, @startdate))
         UNION ALL
         SELECT Dateadd(MONTH, 1, FirstDayOfMonth),
                EndDate = CASE
                            WHEN Dateadd(MONTH, 1, LastDayOfMonth) > @enddate THEN @enddate
                            ELSE Dateadd(MONTH, 1, LastDayOfMonth)
                          END
         FROM   cte
         WHERE  FirstDayOfMonth < Dateadd(month, -1, @enddate))
SELECT FirstDayOfMonth,
       LastDayOfMonth,
       [no-of-days] = datediff(dd,FirstDayOfMonth,LastDayOfMonth) + 1,
       Period = format(LastDayOfMonth,'MMM,yyyy'),
       Year = year(FirstDayOfMonth)
FROM   cte
```

**Result :**

```
╔═════════════════╦════════════════╦════════════╦══════════╦══════╗
║ FirstDayOfMonth ║ LastDayOfMonth ║ no-of-days ║  Period  ║ Year ║
╠═════════════════╬════════════════╬════════════╬══════════╬══════╣
║ 2017-06-26      ║ 2017-07-25     ║         30 ║ Jul,2017 ║ 2017 ║
║ 2017-07-26      ║ 2017-08-25     ║         31 ║ Aug,2017 ║ 2017 ║
║ 2017-08-26      ║ 2017-09-15     ║         21 ║ Sep,2017 ║ 2017 ║
╚═════════════════╩════════════════╩════════════╩══════════╩══════╝
```

For older versions

```
DECLARE @startdate DATE = '2017-07-14',
        @enddate   DATE = '2017-09-15'

SET @startdate = cast(cast(Year(@startdate) AS CHAR(4))+'-'+cast(Month(@startdate) - 1 AS varchar(2))+'-'+ '26' AS date);
WITH cte
     AS (SELECT FirstDayOfMonth = @startdate,
                LastDayOfMonth = Dateadd(dd, -1, Dateadd(month, 1, @startdate))
         UNION ALL
         SELECT Dateadd(MONTH, 1, FirstDayOfMonth),
                EndDate = CASE
                            WHEN Dateadd(MONTH, 1, LastDayOfMonth) > @enddate THEN @enddate
                            ELSE Dateadd(MONTH, 1, LastDayOfMonth)
                          END
         FROM   cte
         WHERE  FirstDayOfMonth < Dateadd(month, -1, @enddate))
SELECT FirstDayOfMonth,
       LastDayOfMonth,
       [no-of-days] = Datediff(dd, FirstDayOfMonth, LastDayOfMonth)
                      + 1,
       Period = Cast(Datename(month, LastDayOfMonth) AS CHAR(3))+','+ Cast(Year(LastDayOfMonth) AS CHAR(4)),
       Year = Year(FirstDayOfMonth)
FROM   cte
```

Comment: Hi Pitsu,Big thanks  exactly what I was looking for, One thing if you can elaborate function, I am using SQL 2008 r2   Datefromparts(Year(@startdate), Month(@startdate) - 1, 26);

Comment: @Ali - `DATEFROMPARTS` is introduced in `sql server 2012` you cannot use it in 2008. check the update

Comment: Hi, Can you check I have rephrased the question, Actually I just want to consider month as 26th (Month start date) and 25th (Month End date).

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to guess what you want as I see many mistakes in your question, but I think you are looking for something like:

```
CREATE TABLE DATA (
    StartDate DATE,
    EndDate DATE,
    DailyRate INT
    );

INSERT INTO DATA VALUES
('2017-06-28', '2017-07-25', 50)

SELECT D.StartDate AS FirstDayOfMonth,
       D.EndDate AS LastDayOfMonth,
       DATEDIFF(DAY, StartDate, EndDate) AS No_Of_Days,
       CAST((DATEDIFF(DAY, StartDate, EndDate) * DailyRate) AS DECIMAL(18,2)) AS MonthlyRevenue,
       DATENAME(Month, EndDate)+ ',' + CAST(DATEPART(Year,EndDate) AS VARCHAR) AS Period,
       DATEPART(Year, EndDate) AS [Year]
FROM DATA AS D;
```

Results:

```
+---------------------+---------------------+------------+----------------+-----------+------+
|   FirstDayOfMonth   |   LastDayOfMonth    | No_Of_Days | MonthlyRevenue |  Period   | Year |
+---------------------+---------------------+------------+----------------+-----------+------+
| 28.06.2017 00:00:00 | 25.07.2017 00:00:00 |         27 |        1350,00 | July,2017 | 2017 |
+---------------------+---------------------+------------+----------------+-----------+------+
```